# Azure Cloud Service Cannot Connect

Tags: azure

I've just tried deploying a Web Role to Azure - using the default settings for the role - haven't changed anything.  The packaging and deployment all went fine, the instance is running, all looks good in the management console etc - no errors.  However, when I try to hit the instance over http, I get a "Cannot Connect" from Google Chrome:

Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to manywho.cloudapp.net

What am I missing?  I have a static page at:

http://manywho.cloudapp.net/bootstrap.html

I also have an ASPX page at:

http://manywho.cloudapp.net/Install.aspx

Any help appreciated.  I'm not a network guy, so I'm not even sure where to start working this through.  My app may not be fully working - but at the moment, I can't even seem to reach it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contact the Windows Azure support http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/contact/ . They're able to investigate the network issues

Answer (score 4):

It turned out to be a couple of things in the end.  As per smarx, port 8080 was incorrectly specified in my ServiceDefinition.csdef file here:

```
<Endpoints>
  <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint1" protocol="http" port="8080" />
</Endpoints>
```

I changed the 8080 to simply 80.  In addition, and super difficult to find, I had specified an httpModule in system.web:

```
<httpModules>
  <add name="SWTModule" type="ManyWho.Flow.Security.SWTModule" />
</httpModules>
```

And this was basically blocking the traffic.  If this is removed and added instead to the system.webServer section as below:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <add name="SWTModule" type="ManyWho.Flow.Security.SWTModule"/>
</modules>
```

It all works.  The SWTModule is something specific to our application to manage security.

Hope that helps others.

Answer (score 0):

http://manywho.cloudapp.net:8080 connects (but gives a 500 error). My guess would be that you have your endpoint set to port 8080 for some reason.